# Brew cannot find git, even though git in path (Mac/OSX)

Tags: git, macos, path, command-line-interface, homebrew

Installing brew reports that it cannot find git, and dies with an error.  Brew appears to have be installed (successfully?)

`> brew`

(prints the usual help)

...but `brew doctor` is not happy:

This is what I get when I run brew doctor, (and when I installed brew for the first time as instructed on the Homebrew homepage.)

```
> brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Git could not be found in your PATH.
Homebrew uses Git for several internal functions, and some formulae use Git
checkouts instead of stable tarballs. You may want to install Git:
  brew install git
Error: Git is unavailable
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core -q
```

My PATH:

```
> echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Git is here:

```
> which git
/usr/bin/git
```

Comment: have you checked if your git version is >= the one brew requires (if it specifies any)

Comment: @pedrorijo91 It doesn’t.

Comment: Please run `cd $(brew --prefix) && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master` then run `brew doctor` again.

Comment: @bfontaine Thanks, but didn't work :<

Comment: @OlaVikholt The commands didn’t work? Or they worked but didn’t solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the command line tools?

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: This is the correct answer if no `brew install` works.

Answer (score -1):

Brew probably works properly for you and you can `brew install` without any issues.

Looks like `brew doctor` would prefer that you install `git` with brew instead of using the OSX system default installation of `git`.

To make `brew doctor` happy, run:

`> brew install git`

That will install `git` to `/usr/local/bin/git` and likely make the error go away.

Comment: This doesn't actually work because you'd need git to install brew's git!